# Adding style by reference to a folder or by wildcard

Tags: angular

Is there any way to load all styles in a particular folder or by wildcard (i.e. *.css) in Angular instead of passing their urls in an array?

Currently I can add styles using the following method `styleUrls: ["default.css", .. ]`,

Comment: You can keep all your styles in styles.css for app.

Comment: @Ahmadmnzr: Terrible solution!

Comment: What is your requirement is difficult to understand.